# Recursively copy a folder and change folder/file names of copied files

Tags: python, node.js, bash

I need to copy a large folder and rename all the files and folders inside if they contain a specific string.  Basically I want to copy everything and change any instance of `10` to `11`.

For example if I have a folder structured like this:

```
mainfolder10
   -group10
       -group10.js
       -group10.html
```

I want it to copy it like this:

```
mainfolder11
   -group11
       -group11.js
       -group11.html
```

I could also copy it first with `cp -r mainfolder10/ mainfolder11/` and then use a different command or script to rename the files.  I'm just looking for anything to not have to do this manually.

I am looking to accomplish this in either bash, node, or python...whatever you all recommend. Does anyone know a simple way to do this?

Comment: If you want to use bash, you can try the `rename` command like `find mainfolder10 -exec rename s/10/11/g "{}" +`

Comment: @LeoPolicastro : So you want to end up with two identical copies of your files, one copy has names with ....10, and the other one has names with .....11? What's the point? Are you reinventing version control?

Comment: No, I need to duplicate files and folders in a google drive and rename them to our next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The usual technique for recursion over directories and files is to use [*os.walk()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
 for root, dirs, files in os.walk('somepath'):
      ...
```

From there, you can use [*os.rename()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) or any of the [*shutils*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#module-shutil) as needed on a file-by-file or directory-by-directory basis.

To avoid confusion, I would rename all the files on the first pass and then make a second pass to rename the directories.

Comment: Thank you I will give this a try, I probably should have mentioned that of the 3 I asked for python is my weakest.

Comment: This is a good Python task to learn with.  Start by using *rename* to rename a file.  Then, try-out *os.walk* with *print()* to see what it does.  Then combine the two :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I finally ended up accomplishing this with the following script.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import tempfile

cohorts_master = Path.home() / "/Users/leo/Desktop/repos/drive-scripts"
cohorts_master

NEEDLE, REPLACEMENT = (f"C{i}" for i in range(39, 41))
src = cohorts_master / f"MIA {NEEDLE}"
src

assert src.exists(), f"'{src}' does not exist"

dest = Path(tempfile.mkdtemp()) / f"MIA {REPLACEMENT}"
print(dest)


try:  # I get errors here. Likely permissions problems. I was getting a partial copy
    shutil.copytree(src, dest)
except Exception as err:
    pass

for item in dest.glob("**/*"):
    shutil.move(item.as_posix(), item.as_posix().replace(NEEDLE, REPLACEMENT))


new_src = dest
new_dest = cohorts_master / dest.name.replace(
    REPLACEMENT, f"{REPLACEMENT}-copied-from-{NEEDLE}"
)
new_src, new_dest


shutil.copytree(new_src, new_dest)
```